# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Resultado

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estoy agregando nuevo codigo PHP a mi plataforma web, la cual utilizo Ajax con Jquery para comunicarla con PHP y hacer esa sincronia de carga y visualizacion, pero se me queda en la carga del "loading.gif" que esta dentro de la funcion cargar_datos() de mi script.js, y al final no obtengo el HTML parseado por "success" de jQuery y un error en consola :(

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Resultado..
    at I.error (jquery.js:2:11744)
    at Y (jquery.js:2:17209)
    at re (jquery.js:2:19983)
    at Function.I [as find] (jquery.js:2:7516)
    at ce.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2:21953)
    at new ce.fn.init (jquery.js:2:22445)
    at ce (jquery.js:2:1077)
    at Object.success (script.js:1:4726)
    at c (jquery.js:2:25266)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2:26015)
```

Uso jQuery: 3.7.0

Y para utilizar ajax con jquery, uso una funcion propia que llamo asi:

**En PHP**

```
<?php
echo '
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="cargar_datos(\'id=cosa1&op=cosa2\', \'capa_resultado\', \'GET\', \'0\');">Clic Aqui</a>
<br><br>
<div id="capa_resultado"></div>
';
?>
```

**En Javascript "script.js"**

```
function cargar_datos(e, t, a, n) {
    var o = get_http_host()
      , c = "https://" + o + "/ajax.php?" + e;
    if (0 == n)
        var r = "GET";
    else {
        var i = "";
        r = "POST",
        i = serielizeJSON(n.split(":"))
    }
    var s = document.getElementById(t);
    0 == n ? $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            s.innerHTML = '<center><img src="https://' + o + '/imagenes/loading.gif"> Cargando...</center>'
        },
        url: c,
        type: r,
        error: function(e, t, a) {
            s.innerHTML = '<center><img src="https://' + o + '/imagenes/error2.png"> Sucedio un error :: ' + t + "</center>",
            console.log(e),
            console.log(a)
        },
        success: function(e) {
            $(e).find("#big_content"),
            $("#" + t).css("display", "none"),
            $("#" + t).parseHTML(e),
            $("#" + t).fadeIn("slow")
        }
    }) : $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            s.innerHTML = '<center><img src="https://' + o + '/imagenes/loading.gif"> Cargando...</center>'
        },
        url: c,
        type: r,
        data: i,
        error: function(e, t, a) {
            s.innerHTML = '<center><img src="https://' + o + '/imagenes/error2.png"> Sucedio un error :: ' + t + "</center>",
            console.log(e),
            console.log(a)
        },
        success: function(e) {
            $(e).find("#big_content"),
            $("#" + t).css("display", "none"),
            $("#" + t).parseHTML(e),
            $("#" + t).fadeIn("slow")
        }
    })
}
```

El archivo **ajax.php** que llama la 3er linea de la funcion "cargar_datos()", si existe y funciona porque si doy clic en otros botones y enlaces, el proceso corre sin problema.

Archivo ajax.php

```
<?php
echo 'Resultado..';
?>
```

Comment: Hola, a simple vista diría que el problema se debe a esta línea `$(e).find("#big_content")`. Supuestamente `e` es igual a `Resultado..`, no es un selector. Te sugiero borrarla.

Comment: @Marcos agregue la capa #big_content despues de <body> y eso soluciono el problema